# ASP.Net MVC 5 ActionResult throwing 404 exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a major brain freeze :
I have an MVC 5 project that uses  bootstrap popover forms for date data input.  The popovers are invoked on the main landing page and data is stringified JSON  forwarded to the ActionResult function in the Home controller, which then accesses the SQL server db and returns a JSON dataset which is used to build a D3 based visualization rendered in a cshtml view.
To this point every thing works the data is valid the model and viz have been unit tested.  The Home controller has  two controllers :
The popover  js script (cribbed from http://jsfiddle.net/itsabhik/cxm4rt2u/2/):

```
        $('.main-attributes').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
        $('.submit').click(function () {
            var fromval = $('.popover #fromvalue').val();
            var toval = $('.popover #tovalue').val();
                    var option = {
                        url: '/Home/LoanCount',
                        data: JSON.stringify({ dStart: fromval, dEnd: toval }),
                        method: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
                    };

            $.ajax(option).done(function (data) {
                        return (data);
            })
            $('.main-attributes').popover('hide');
        });
        $('.cancel').click(function () {
            $('.main-attributes').popover('hide');
        });
    });
```

And the controller code :

```
        public ActionResult LoanCount(DateTime dStart, DateTime dEnd)
    {
        int iStart = (dStart.Year * 10000) + (dStart.Month * 100) + dStart.Day;
        int iEnd = (dEnd.Year * 10000) + (dEnd.Month * 100) + dEnd.Day;

        var json = Models.LoanCount.getCountStats (iStart, iEnd);
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.LoanCount>> (json);

        ViewBag.jData = json;

        return Redirect ("/Views/Home/LoanCount.cshtml");  /* This is one of the 
                                    redirect variations                                             that have been tried */
    }
```

The problem that I am having is that all the Redirect variations that I use throw a 404 not found exception.  Invoking RedirectToAction(...), a parameterless ActionResult, throws a 403 exception.  The cshtml file exists and the path is verified and correct.

The browser being used is Chrome.  What is missing - any clues, advice on this issue ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want a redirect returned, but if you just return the view from your Home/LoanCount - does the route work?

Comment: I want to pass SQL query parameters from a main page using popover forms.  The parameters produce a range of data to assess process performance of different entities in the enterprise.

Comment: I want to pass SQL query parameters from a main application page using data entered via popover forms.  The parameters produce a range of data to assess process performance, and in general to generate BI dashboards of different entities in the enterprise.  The Home/LoanCount route works fine and was implemented in the first cut in order to test the D3 based visualization pages.  The SQL query parameters were hard-coded in the model classes to simplify the debug process.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried making the Redirect to a Controller Method or a full url instead of the view?

Comment: Yes.  The result is the same.

Comment: Brain freeze fix : the controller was ignoring the redirect since the route to the controller was invoked by an ajax call which was a callback to the original page.

Answer (score 0):

You can return view with tilde(~) prefix. In this reason URL will not be changed.

```
return View("~/Views/Home/LoanCount.cshtml");
```

If you want to change the URL you have to use `RedirectToAction` method with controller name and method name.

Answer (score 0):

Previous comment : fat-fingered the Enter key.  The fix was to disable the ajax func since it was posting a callback, redo the URL with the parameter values and define the window location rather than issue an ajax call.  It's working as expected now. Whew !!

```
        $('.main-attributes').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
        $('.submit').click(function () {
            var fromval = $('.popover #fromvalue').val();
            var toval = $('.popover #tovalue').val();
            var option = {
                url: "/Home/LoanCount?dStart=" + fromval + "&" + "dEnd=" + toval,
                data: JSON.stringify({ dStart: fromval, dEnd: toval }),
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            };

            window.location.href = option.url;

            $('.main-attributes').popover('hide');
        });

        $('.cancel').click(function () {
            $('.main-attributes').popover('hide');
        });
    });
```

The controller :

```
        public ActionResult LoanCount(DateTime dStart, DateTime dEnd)
    {
        int iStart = (dStart.Year * 10000) + (dStart.Month * 100) + dStart.Day;
        int iEnd = (dEnd.Year * 10000) + (dEnd.Month * 100) + dEnd.Day;

        var json = Models.LoanCount.getCountStats (iStart, iEnd);
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.LoanCount>> (json);

        ViewBag.jData = json;

        return View ("~/Views/Home/LoanCount.cshtml");
    }
```